# What is the history of electricity

Tags: electricity

Could someone please explain how the concept of electricity was originally conceived and how it became connected with time? Also how did people come about the relationship between time and electricity?

Comment: What do you mean by a relation with "time."  ? Everything is time-dependent .

Comment: These types of questions are too broad for this site, and are already answered by encyclopedias, e.g. [Wikipedia, History of Electricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity#History).

Answer (score 2):

An answer to this question requires a whole book, and such book indeed exists:
E. T. Whittaker, A history of the theories of aether and electricity from the age of Descartes to the close of nineteenth century. There are many editions. The later editions, in 2 volumes, bring the history to the 1920th,
including quantum mechanics and general relativity.

Complete (classical) theory of electricity was created by Maxwell (based on earlier research of many people like Volta, Galvani, Ampere, Ohm, Kirkhoff, Faraday and many others). His
book Treatise on electricity and magnetism also contains a complete history,
up to the end of 19th century.